# Environment variables manipulation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

When using:

```
echo "${env.PRODUCT_NAME}"
```

it will echo:

> MyProdName

When using:

```
echo "${env.MyProdName_Key}"
```

it will echo:

> 123456789

I would like to use something as follows:

```
echo "${env.${env.PRODUCT_NAME}_Key}"
```

Is this possible? How?

Comment: The language behind that is Groovy btw.

Comment: What happens when you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

In Bash this is termed as variable in direction

Try using variables to make it further simplified

```
PRODUCT_NAME=$(echo "${env.PRODUCT_NAME}")
```

This would assign PRODUCT_NAME=MyProdName

Similarly

```
 MyProdName=$(echo "${env.MyProdName_Key}")
```

This would assign MyProdName=123456789

Now when you print PRODUCT_NAME value you will get

```
echo ${PRODUCT_NAME}
MyProdName
```

And adding '!' variable indirection will give you the value of another variable values

```
   echo ${!PRODUCT_NAME}
   123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you somehow:

```
def env = [
    PRODUCT_NAME:'MyProdName',
    MyProdName_Key: 123456789,
]

println "${env[env.PRODUCT_NAME+'_Key']}"
```

`env` is `Map` in the example provided but it works in the exactly same way.

Answer (score 0):

Important note, regardless of how you're deriving variables:

> There's no need to use string interpolation if the only value in a
>   string is a variable itself. This just clutters your code.
>
> Instead of: 
>   `echo "${env.PRODUCT_NAME}"`
>
> you can do: 
>   `echo.PRODUCT_NAME`.

Additionally you can grab nested object values dynamically using bracket notation

> `def obj = [a: '1']
>   echo obj[a]            // outputs '1'`

Using these put together, you can do:

`def prodName = env.PRODUCT_NAME     //will set var prodName to "MyProdName"
 echo env[prodName + '_Key']     //gets nested field with key "MyProdName_Key"`

(Note: this is similar to Opal's answer, hopefully my breakdown helps)